# Problems using cygwin+vim as TFS diff utility

Tags: vim, tfs

I am attempting to set up vim on cygwin on mintty as my custom diff tool in TFS (2012), and I am having problems with the temp files disappearing before vim can look at them.  I'll first run through what I've tried so far:

When I noticed my issue I tried to just use the native windows vim.exe, and it works fine under the windows console with the following settings:

[image: using vim.exe as diff tool in TFS]

I can also get it to work fine with the cygwin copy of vim run inside of the windows console:

[image: using cygwin's vim, still under cmd.exe]

But once I try to use mintty I get empty files opened in vim, and the files passed to vim by TFS do not exist in the TFSTemp directory:

[image: use mintty to run vim under cygwin]

[image: vim sees nonexistent files]

I think there is some Windows magic going on with the C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\TFSTemp directory.  In the first two cases I can navigate to that directory in the windows explorer and find the files passed to vim.  When I use mintty, however, the files do not show up in explorer.  I suspect this has something to do with how TFS handles its temp files.  Perhaps the layer of indirection provided by mintty is somehow being misinterpreted by TFS as me closing out of the diff utility?

I'm not familiar enough with the inner workings of Windows or TFS to know why this is happening, but my google-fu has yielded ONE single result that seems to be related to my issue:
http://www.scootersoftware.com/vbulletin/showthread.php?5538-Beyond-Compare-and-TFS-Problems-with-temporary-files

The first poster was having the same missing file problems with the beyondcompare diff utility, and the company response indicated that the wrong executable was being used.  Apparently one of their two similarly-named executables will keep a separate process open for every comparison, while the other will only use a single process, and the missing file problem happens if you use the single-process executable for TFS.  I'm not sure how this maps to my issue.

That is all I've been able to find on this issue, so any help is appreciated.  At the moment I'm attempting to make a workaround .bat file to save the temp files in a different directory before starting mintty, but this seems a bit kludgy to me (and my batch scripting skills are quite rudimentary/nonexistent).

**Update:**
I have come up with a serviceable solution with a batch script to start mintty which then uses the sleep command afterwards. This keeps the files open long enough so that vim can open buffers for them, which is enough for me (I'm just viewing the diff). After the sleep command is done the files are deleted (I'm assuming by TFS). If I end the script with a pause command the files are left in the TMP folder until I press a key in the cmd.exe window.

Answer (score 0):

There should be nothing different  how TFS handles its temp files with other folder.

To narrow down it:

- You can try again with some windows temp folder or VS temp folder
- You can also try to change the  TFS Temp Folder such as   `set TMP=D:\Temp set TEMP=%TMP%  md %TMP%`  detail steps please refer the blog
  from MSDN: [Change TFS Temp Folder](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mohamedg/2009/04/13/how-to-change-tfs-temp-folder/)

Comment: I thought about doing that, but I figured I would avoid the potential problems with changing that environment variable when other programs could potentially be using it.  I have since used a batch script to start mintty, and using the sleep command afterwards keeps the files open long enough so that vim can open buffers for them.  After the sleep command is done the files are deleted (I'm assuming by TFS).  If I end the script with a pause command the files are left in the TMP folder until I press a key in the cmd.exe window.

Comment: Suggest you to add your solution as a separate answer and mark it instead  of adding it in the update.  This will also help others in SO get better search results.